# SQL Show multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is show all the information about the countries from Asia and Europe, but not the other continents. Then order them by continent. I'm just missing something obvious, but what is it?

If I put `AND` between Asia and Europe then it will try to show countries that are from both Asia and Europe, so that won't do but if I put OR then it will only display Asia.

What my code looks like;

```
SELECT * 
FROM country
WHERE Continent = 'Asia' AND 'Europe'
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent = 'Asia' OR Continent = 'Europe'
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. Works well and I understand what I did wrong now.

Answer (score 6):

Try following

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent in ('Asia','Europe')
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent IN ('Asia','Europe')
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent ='Asia' OR Continent= 'Europe'
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent In( 'Asia' , 'Europe')
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

(Or)

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent ='Asia' OR Continent= 'Europe'
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

(Or)

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent ='Asia'
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE Continent ='Europe'
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM country
WHERE Continent = "Africa" OR Continent = "Australia"
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

And incase if you want non africans and australians

```
SELECT *
FROM country
WHERE !(Continent = "Africa" AND Continent = "Australia") 
ORDER BY Continent DESC;
```

Comment: There are more than 4 continents in the world.